# how to pull joomla page title into amazon native shopping ads search field in widget code?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

How can pull joomla page titles into the amazon native shopping ads search field in amazon native shopping ads widget code?

According to
https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/help/t402#search
it is very possible to do this, 
using
amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = "your-search-phrase";

But I don't know exactly how to go about implementing this

> How do I programmatically drive the search results of the ad unit? The
>   ad code for Native Shopping Ads is a simple list of javascript
>   variables and is highly programmable. To programmatically specify the
>   search key phrase to be displayed: amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase =
>   "your-search-phrase"; The search phrase could potentially be driven by
>   any of the parameters available in your CMS or by the search term
>   entered by the visitors to your site.

any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

try this

$mydoc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$title = $mydoc->getTitle();

Comment: I have tried 
amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = "$mydoc =& JFactory::getDocument(); $title = $mydoc->getTitle();";  
 
and 

amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = "<?php $mydoc =& JFactory::getDocument(); $title = $mydoc->getTitle();
 ?>";

am i doing it right? as I am not a coder, so I'm unsure exactly how to do it,  neither way worked.  Any help is appreciated.